# Fragment displays inside the xml preview but not upon app launch Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have an application that uses 2 fragments and are displayed side by side. When I add another fragment view it does not display. This is my code: 
The fragment is called @+id/fragment1 located at the bottom of the xml file. Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.37" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:name="com.davila.fundamentals.MasterFragment"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dummy_view"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment1"
                android:name="com.davila.fundamentals.PreferenceFragment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why the fragment was not displaying. It turns out that I was not calling the commit() method at the end of your fragment instance:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(...).commit();
```

This solved the issue.